# how to iterate the actual node and descendants?

Tags: c#, xml

I have this xml file:

```
<Assemblies>
  <Assembly Name="MyMainAssambly.exe" Version="1.7.0.0" Path="x:\MyMainAssemby.exe" >
    <NeededAssemblies>
      <Assembly Name="Aseembly01.dll" Version="1.1.1.1" Path="x:\Assembly01.dll"/>
      <Assembly Name="Aseembly02.dll" Version="2.2.2.2" Path="x:\Assembly02.dll"/>
      <Assembly Name="Aseembly03.dll" Version="3.3.3.3" Path="x:\Assembly03.dll"/>
    </NeededAssemblies>
  </Assembly>
</Assemblies>
```

I want to iterate all of them to do some tasks. So I am trying to use this code:

```
            XElement myMainAssembly = miDocumentoXml.Root.Elements("Assembly")
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == "MyMainAssembly.exe"
                        && x.Attribute("Version").Value.StartsWith("1.7.0.0"))
                .FirstOrDefault();



foreach (XElement nodeIterator in myMainAssembly.DescendantNodesAndSelf())
{
    //Do some code with the nodes Assembly01.dll, Assembly02.dll and Assembly, using the name, version and path.

    string miStrAssemblyName = nodeIterator .Attribute("Name").Value;
}
```

But if I debbug and set a break point, I can see that the property HasAttributes of all elements is false. Why? Because in the xml all the elements have 3 attriibutes. In fact, in the first part of code, where I get my main assembly, I can use Attribute("Name") to get the name of the main assembly. But later in the foreach I can't.

So I would like to know how to iterate the elements and get the information of the attributes.

Thanks.

Comment: `"MyMainAssambly"` is not the same string as `"MyMainAssembly"`. "Assemby" and "Aseembly" don't match up with anything either.

Comment: Use List<XElement> myMainAssembly and then From : FirstOrDefault()  To : ToList() so you get more than one object.

Comment: Once I correct the typo, your problem seems to be that `<NeededAssemblies>` has no attribute called "Name". If I filter out elements with no "Name" attribute, the other three "Assembly" elements are fine, Name and all. `HasAttributes` is true for each of them.